# Using ng-if to show certain things if condition is met

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, servicenow, angularjs-ng-if

I'm trying to use `ng-if` to show certain rows if the condition is met, but can't quite seem to get it to work 100% correctly.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">

  <h4><!-- content omitted for brevity--></h4>

  <p>
    <strong>Covered:</strong> &nbsp;
    <a ng-href class="pointer" data-ng-repeat="life in data.list2 track by $index" ng-if="life.beneficiary.length > 0" ng-click="c.editBeneficiary(life)">

      <!-- content omitted for brevity-->
    </a>

    <a ng-href class="pointer" ng-if="life.beneficiary.length = 0" ng-click="c.addBeneficiary()">Add Beneficiary&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="color: green;"/></a></p>

</div>
```

In the above code, if the number of *beneficiaries* is greater than 0 (`ng-if="life.beneficiary.length > 0"`), I want to list out the names and allow the user to edit them if necessary. This part is working fine.  However, if the number of *beneficiaries* equals 0, then I want to have a link that says "Add Beneficiary", and allow the user to do so.

I put the `ng-if` statements in the `<a>` tag, which I'm not sure is right.  When I log in with a user who does NOT have a beneficiary, the "Add Beneficiary" link doesn't show up.

- What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `life.beneficiary.length = 0` is NOT a comparison, it's trying to assign `0` (zero) value to `life.beneficiary.length`(which is wrong).

Besides, when there is not beneficiaries `life.beneficiary.length == 0` (which is correct) might be falsy because `life.beneficiary` could be `null` or `undefined` (it depends on your controller logic)... but, in order to solve this try:

**Change** `ng-if="life.beneficiary.length = 0"` **to** `ng-if="!life.beneficiary.length"` (this is equivalent to `ng-if="life.beneficiary.length == 0"`, but it won't fail in your logic if `life.beneficiary` is `null` or `undefined`)

```
<a ng-href class="pointer" ng-if="!life.beneficiary.length" ng-click="c.addBeneficiary()">Add Beneficiary&nbsp;
</a>
```

Also, it is recommended to wrap both links (`<a>`) inside an element (`span`, `div`, ... as you wish) which will contain the `ng-repeat`, something like this:

```
<p>
<!-- there is content omitted for brevity -->
  <span data-ng-repeat="life in data.list2 track by $index">

    <a class="pointer" ng-if="life.beneficiary.length > 0" ng-click="c.editBeneficiary(life)">

    <!-- content omitted for brevity-->
    </a>

    <a class="pointer" ng-if="!life.beneficiary.length" ng-click="c.addBeneficiary()">Add Beneficiary&nbsp;</a>

  </span>

</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem of having his `ng-repeat` on the first `<a>` instead having an `ng-repeat` on both`<a>` tags or on a container element.

Comment: @kennypowers, I'm sorry, I don't understand clearly what you're trying to say :( The OP put in his question only one `ng-repeat`. I saw your answer as well, but I don't get it yet. What do you need the second `ng-repeat` for? I think you might assumed that part. That code will generate a completely different html from the one that would be generated from the one posted in the question.

Comment: The first `<a>` tag is the element that is repeating. He kind of has all his html on a single line so it's hard to tell...Since that is the case, the second `<a>` tag and `ng-if` are not doing anything. Unless I'm going blind...

Comment: Oh, I understand the confusion now (yours or mine, only the OP can tell). I assumed that all the <a> tag which call the `editBeneficiary` function were necessary inside the `ng-repeat` (because they are there for editing the element) and a last one for adding a new beneficiary (but just once at the end). You thought in a different behavior obviously (I'm not saying at all it's wrong. Maybe asking to the OP is a good idea :) ).

Comment: hey sorry for the confusion, I want the ng-repeat to dynamically create rows if beneficiaries exist.  If beneficiaries do NOT exist, I just want to display a link that says "Add Beneficiary" which opens up a modal window for them to do so.  Would I still need ng-repeat on the second <a> tag if this is the case?

Comment: No, I think you don't, Dave. With the answer provided above I think you can solve your problem.

Comment: @Dave you are using `life` in the `ng-if` in your second `<a>` tag. But `life` doesn't exist there. The second `<a>` tag is outside of the `ng-repeat` where `life` is created. Thus you need to create a container element, like a `<div>`, and add the `ng-repeat` to that. Inside of that `<div>`, you can put both `<a>` tags with separate `ng-if` statements. This will get you what you want. OR you can add the same `ng-repeat` to both `<a>` tags.

Comment: @Dave, @kennypowers, I agree, I didn't realize life was being gotten from the `data.list2`. I updated the answer. Please, see the section **EDITED**

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this

```
ng-if="life.beneficiary.length = 0"
```

In

```
ng-if="life.beneficiary.length == 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up currently, it is only going to show the `<a>` tags that meet the first `ng-if` requirement. Both of your `<a>` tags need an `ng-repeat` statement along with the proper `ng-if` statement:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
<h4>
    <img class="icon" src="basic_life.png" height="30" width="30"> &nbsp;<strong>Insured?</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;<font size=2>
        <i class="fa {{data.icon}}" style="color:{{data.color}}" /> {{data.status}}
    </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</h4>
<p>
    <strong>Covered:</strong> &nbsp;
    <a ng-href class="pointer" data-ng-repeat="life in data.list2 track by $index" ng-if="life.beneficiary.length > 0"
       ng-click="c.editBeneficiary(life)">
        <font ng-show="$last && !$first">&nbsp;and&nbsp;</font>{{life.beneficiary}}&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <i class="fa fa-edit" /><font ng-show="!$last">,&nbsp;</font>
    </a>
    <a ng-href class="pointer" data-ng-repeat="life in data.list2 track by $index" ng-if="!life.beneficiary.length" ng-click="c.addBeneficiary()">
        Add Beneficiary&nbsp;
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="color: green;" />
    </a>
</p>
```

If you want it under a single ng-repeat you would need to do something like this:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
<h4>
    <img class="icon" src="basic_life.png" height="30" width="30"> &nbsp;<strong>Insured?</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;<font size=2>
        <i class="fa {{data.icon}}" style="color:{{data.color}}" /> {{data.status}}
    </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</h4>
<p>
    <strong>Covered:</strong> &nbsp;
    <div data-ng-repeat="life in data.list2 track by $index">
        <a ng-href class="pointer"  ng-if="life.beneficiary.length > 0"
           ng-click="c.editBeneficiary(life)">
            <font ng-show="$last && !$first">&nbsp;and&nbsp;</font>{{life.beneficiary}}&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <i class="fa fa-edit" /><font ng-show="!$last">,&nbsp;</font>
        </a>
        <a ng-href class="pointer" ng-if="life.beneficiary.length = 0" ng-click="c.addBeneficiary()">
            Add Beneficiary&nbsp;
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="color: green;" />
        </a>
    </div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**

1. Use life.beneficiary.length === 0 instead life.beneficiary.length = 0
2. = is used for assignment and == or === is used for comparison.

or, you can also use this optimized logic.

1. ng-if="life.beneficiary.length"

if beneficiary length is 0 then link will be hidden else it will show up.

**

```
<a ng-href class="pointer" ng-if="life.beneficiary.length === 0" ng-click="c.addBeneficiary()">Add Beneficiary&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="color: green;"/></a></p>
```